# how to change background of a form on a value returning from serial

Tags: c#

I'm new to c#,i have been trying to change the color of form when I receive a value from a serial, I am using event handling method to receive data from serial monitor, yet the output is not coming. I have here by attached the code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SerialPort port;

       public delegate void UpdateGUI(string str);
       public void DisplayReceivedData(string str)
       {
           string ja = "12";
          //listBox1.Items.Add("received");
         //  if(StringComparison
            listBox1.Items.Add(str);
            textBox1.Text = ja;
            int test = String.Compare(str, ja);
            textBox1.Text =Convert.ToString(str);
            if (test == 0)
            {
                ActiveForm.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkBlue;
            }
            else
            {
                ActiveForm.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            }

        }
        public void Datareceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs arg)
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            string str = sp.ReadExisting();
            Invoke(new UpdateGUI(DisplayReceivedData),str);

        } 
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            port = new SerialPort("COM10");
            port.BaudRate = 9600;
            port.Parity = Parity.None;
            port.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            port.DataBits = 8;
            port.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            port.RtsEnable = true;
            port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(Datareceived);
            port.Open();
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ActiveForm.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkBlue;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ActiveForm.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;

        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: is test variable set to 0??

Comment: nope,it doesnt,but when i look into the listbox it displays 12 consecutively,i dunno how to control that as well

Comment: try to debug and see what value is set to str

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Is the problem that the received string has never the value 12? Is the problem that the back color never turns dark blue? Perhaps you could enhance a little bit the question.

Comment: @AlejandroGonzález  i have to receive 12 from serial ,this 12 is saved in str ,when str is equal to ja the value must change ,when i open list box the value 12 is received continously,yet when i compare both the string ,its says that the stirng received is not correct

Comment: Did you try `.Trim()`? if it's always a number, maybe you should try converting to int - `int.Parse(str)`

Comment: You'll have to stop relying on ReadExisting().  You only ever get "12" when you slow down your program enough with a debugger.  Without a debugger what is typically existing in the receive buffer is "1" or "2".  Do not call Invoke() until you received the full response.  Knowing that you got a full response typically requires a protocol or a fixed number of bytes in the response so you can count them off.

Comment: @HansPassant not able to get you can u explain in brief pls

Comment: @OfirWinegarten yes but it didnt work,,

Comment: guyd i just figure the problem ,i checked the the value i recive "str" in debugger it shows str pocess '\r''\n'.when i try to remove it it isnt removing .is there any method to remove it,i have used .trim(),.replace(),but couldnt reach th result

Answer (score 0):

As you say in your comments the problem is with the end-of-line chars.

You could simply trim them off using:

```
str.TrimEnd('\r', '\n');
```